# SharefileClient's UploadRangeAsync overrides with blank spaces previous content when adding more text to a file (C#)

Tags: c#, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files, fileshare, storage-access-api

I'm creating a method to append new text to an existing file in an Azure File Share. This is the code:

```
 public async Task AppendAllTextAsync(string path, string text)
        {
            var fileClient = _fileShare.GetRootDirectoryClient().GetFileClient(path);

            var currentFileLength = fileClient.GetProperties().Value.ContentLength;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)))
            {
                await fileClient.CreateAsync(currentFileLength + ms.Length);
                await fileClient.UploadRangeAsync(new HttpRange(currentFileLength - 1, ms.Length), ms);
            }
        }
```

When I test with a sample txt file whose initial content is this:
[image: Sample text file]

it removes all the content and append the content at the end.
For example, if I call my method like this on the said file
`accessor.AppendAllText("Sample file.txt", " 2");`

Then the file shows:
[image: Sample file after appending text]

So it's like removing all the previous content when offsetting.

Any ideas on why it's happening or a way of doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Byt As Byte() = MSt.ToArray
Dim currentFileLength As Long = (Await File.GetPropertiesAsync()).Value.ContentLength
Await File.SetHttpHeadersAsync(currentFileLength + Byt.Length)
Dim SFW As Stream = Await File.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite:=False, position:=currentFileLength)
Await SFW.WriteAsync(Byt, 0, Byt.Length)
Await SFW.FlushAsync()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).